# How can I find the directory to clang-format

Tags: vim, gvim, clang

I use gvim to code and want to use clang-format as a plugin.
As I read it is already [integrated in vim](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#vim-integration). I just need to add this line to my .vimrc:

```
map <C-K> :pyf <path-to-this-file>/clang-format.py<cr>
```

Unfortunately I can't find the `<path-to-this-file>`.
I already installed the clang-format-3.6 via apt-get.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I suspect it's `/usr/share/vim/addons/syntax/clang-format-3.6.py` (note the version number in the filename) - but check using `dpkg -L clang-format-3.6`

Answer (score 0):

It is clang-format-diff (without .py extension) in clang-format installed path.
In my case

`/usr/bin/clang-format-diff-6.0 (I am using 6.0)`